# Is it possible to use parallel tasks to update DataRows in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, parallel-processing

I want to improve the performance of updating the rows of a `DataTable`.  In one example, I need to operate on a `DateTime` column, converting the `System.DateTime` value to a home-grown wrapper class.  Meaning that currently, I loop over the `Rows` collection, and set each column of each row in series.

An example of what I do now:

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("fldDateCreated", typeof(TypedDateTime)));
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (!(row["~fldDateCreated"] is DBNull))
        row["fldDateCreated"] = new TypedDateTime((DateTime)row["~fldDateCreated"]);
}
dt.Columns.Remove("~fldDateCreated");
```

I would love to do this in parallel, but [as MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.90).aspx) and my tests prove, `DataTable` does not like this sort of thing.

They state (for both `DataTable` and `DataRow`):

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must
>   synchronize any write operations.

I have tried alternatives such as capturing the row data into `Object[]`, updating that in parallel, and then updating the `DataTable` from those results.  However, the price of finding and updating each row appears to be far more expensive than the original loop.

Is there a way forward here?  Can I process these row updates in some threaded/parallel fashion?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Updating rows in a datatable shouldn't take too long. If it does, something's wrong. How many rows do you have and why do you use a DataTable instead of a collection of plain objects? Why would you have a lot of records in memory in the first place?

Comment: I'm assuming you have good reason for using a `DataTable`, in the first place.

Comment: What have you tried to  do this in parallel? Show also that code. I doubt that you can improve performance significantly. It's also not clear why you need your `TypedDateTime`. If performance matters so much and the table is so large that you think that you need to do this in parallel, why don't you use a database instead? Or instead of  a weakly typed `DataTable` a `List<YourType>`.

Comment: 1) About 100k rows;  2) because it's going to be bound to a grid control for display;  3) the wrapper class provides tools I need internally that go beyond DateTime.

Comment: Besides, fiddling with an object from multiple threads always causes issues. The trick is to extract the data you want, spread it to multiple threads for processing then collect it back. In other words, don't iterate over the table, extract and process all rows eg with PLINQ, putting all values in a single collection.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've come across that term before, but I am not at all familiar with what PLINQ is or how I might use it.

Comment: @DonBoitnott that a **very** strong smell. A grid won't display more rows than there is screen space. If you bind all data to it, you are simply wasting resources. All grids support virtualization, ie loading only the rows they need to display and scroll a few pages ahead or back (if even that)

Comment: In other words, parallelization here will only get you in trouble faster.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Point taken.  But irrelevant to the question.  It's an architecture issue that I cannot simply change.  For now, I am trying to gain performance where I can.

Comment: You can't because you are trying to fix what isn't broken. Besides, why do you add the extra column *after* loading instead of while loading?

Answer (score 0):

here you go,

```
// referencing
//    System.Data.DataSetExtensions
//    System.Linq.Parallel

dt.AsEnumerable().AsParalell()
    .Where(row => !(row["~fldDateCreated"] is DBNull))
    .ForAll(row =>
    {
        row.SetField(
            "fldDateCreated",
            new TypedDateTime((DateTime)row["~fldDateCreated"]));
    });
```

Comment: This won't help with the real problem. The OP wants to bind 100K rows to a grid.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, then the OP should delete this question and ask the real one. Sounds like he wants paging.